# How can you check if a string ends with a specific substring?

Tags: string, coldfusion

Is there a coldfusion string function to check if a string ends with another string? If not, what is the simplest and most efficient way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the `right(string, numberofcharacters)` function.

example (cfscript):

```
existingString = "The Quick brown Fox jumps";
tailString = "umps";
stringMatch = false;
if (right(existingString, len(tailString)) eq tailString){
   stringMatch = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This looks like a good solution... I think I'm going to stick to mine since the substrings I'm looking for are a combination of a couple of alphabetic characters... but thanks for your response!

Comment: @froadie Your string will always be a combination of a couple of alpha characters... until the day it isn't.  Why leave a potential bug when there's a clearer, safer, better solution.  Don't assUme.

Answer (score 13):

This is where I skip down to the java level real fast.

```
string = "This is my fancy string";

<cfoutput>#string.endsWith("string")#</cfoutput>
```

This should output TRUE

More details here:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith(java.lang.String)

Note that endsWith() is case sensitive.

To get around this, use LCase() or UCase(), e.g.

```
Ucase(string).endsWith("STRING");
```

Should also return TRUE

Answer (score 2):

A solution that I found ( http://tutorial130.easycfm.com/ ) -
Use a regular expression find - `REFindNoCase`, with a `$` sign to represent the end of the string.

```
REFindNoCase("end$", "check if this string ends with end")
```

Comment: This function works well if you only want to compare literal characters. You will run into problems if your search string contains special characters with a meaning in regex. Like .?$+*. You will have to escape them first

Comment: There's no need for regex here. @Andreas Schuldhaus's solution is better and he's explained why regex will cause headaches. To wit: "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems." http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html

Comment: I personally like regex, but this is an example where it's overkill.  The left() method listed above is more efficient.